# Terraform best practise for near identical iam_policy_document's for each environment to avoid duplication

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-modules

What’s the best practise for handling policy documents that are entirely the same for each environment apart from an ID within them?

- Initially, the codebase I was using simply duplicated these policies
  in the iam.tf file with the ID changed in each environments resource
  definition. It’s a single workspace monolithic repo that I can’t
  change.
- I then refactored it to be a module which creates the policy
  with the ID as a variable.
- I then found out about templatefiles in
  terraform so I refactored it to instead be a policy .tftpl file in a
  subdirectory and then I call templatefile() with the different
  variable for each environment.

I’m aware that the recommended convention for policy documents is to implement them as a data object, but my understanding is I can’t then parameterise it to prevent entire policy documents being repeated save for a single variable (unless I modularise it like I did initially).

Does anyone have any advice on the best practise for this scenario?

Comment: Can you provide any example code demonstrating your issue and the duplication problem?

Comment: It's just an iam_policy_document that is 99% the same but for an ID that is different per environment.

Comment: "I’m aware that the recommended convention for policy documents is to implement them as a data object, but my understanding is I can’t then parameterise it to prevent entire policy documents being repeated save for a single variable (unless I modularise it like I did initially)." Why don't you think you can use parameters/variables in a data source IAM policy?

Comment: Because a data source is defined object. I can't dynamically get it with a different variable to use in each place without putting it in a module which takes variables. If I'm wrong can you explain to me how I would parameterise a data {} policy document to handle my use case?

Comment: @James: Sure you can. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely parameterize the [aws_iam_policy_document data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document).

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  for_each = toset(["bucket-a", "bucket-b"])

  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:*"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${each.key}"]
  }
}
```

You can follow this pattern for attachment too:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "this" {
  for_each = toset(["bucket-a", "bucket-b"])

  name_prefix = each.key
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[each.key].json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "this" {
  for_each = toset(["bucket-a", "bucket-b"])

  name       = "${each.key}-attachment"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.this[each.key].arn
  # things to attach to
}
```

Comment: How would I 'get' each of the separate policies to use in each of the separate iam policy attachments?

Comment: `data.aws_iam_policy_document.this["bucket-a"]` and `data.aws_iam_policy_document.this["bucket-b"]`

Comment: Yessss thank you! This is exactly the solution I have been trying to find! I knew my other attempts were over-engineering and there must be a simpler way to do this and you have provided that solution. Thank you - theherk!